# Linux: change OS source code OR automate launching a script

Tags: linux, bash

Here's exactly what I want to do: have a script that, upon detecting that a new file has been put into a predefined directory, runs a little filename scan & move algorithm.

Simple example: I choose to monitor /home/myname/Downloads. Say the state of that folder changed, someClass.java was just added. My algorithm decides to send it to /workspace and does it.

Writing the algorithm is easy. What I'm asking is how to make this monitoring happen. 
I see 2options: 
-find Linux's own file operations script and add my code there
-have a normal bash script that somehow gets notified and run when stuff happens in folders

Or am I completely off?

Comment: [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand upon Ignacio's suggestion to use [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en): Linux provides an `inotify(7)` mechanism that allows programs to *watch* files and directories for modifications. (This was especially nice for KDE and GNOME `explorer.exe` clones -- allow directory listings to update immediately when new files are added or removed, without a [busy-wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) constant re-polling for directory contents.)

Using `inotify_add_watch(2)` directly though is tedious programming. I'm thrilled to find `incron` (thanks again to Ignacio), it sounds like a perfect reusable tool to make working with `inotify(7)` easy for everyone in a declarative syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As @ignocio mentioned, `incron` will work.  However, if you're just starting, here is something a lot more common.

Look into `cron`.  It will let you run scripts at set time intervals.  Not great for this situation, but you could run it once per minute, hour, day, month, day of the week, etc.

Either way, in the script, do an `ls` to grab all the files in the appropriate directory.  Put them in an array, loop through them, and process as appropriate.

Comment: Yea, cron really doesn't fit here, it's either too costly or too slow... Thank you though!